# Ajax fetching data.But also showing error with datatype Json.But working with datatype html

Tags: ajax

I am trying to fetch the data from php file by passing dynamic query string on ajax URL section.But while I changing datatype html to json. It is popping up error

```
jQuery(".nks_cc_trigger_element").click(function(){
        var str = jQuery(this).attr("data-product_id");
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_product.php?q="+parseInt(str), 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
        jQuery("#nks-content-1 > div").html(result);
        console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
        if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
        alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
        }else{
        alert("Something went wrong");
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
        }
        }).done(function() {

        }); 
    >>PHP CODE  

    echo json_encode($data) ;
```

Comment: If you are trying to fetch data, then instead of POST, you should use GET verb.

Comment: @ParthoGanguly..Thanks for your reply. I am trying to fetch the data as well as html.But problem is datatype:html taking a lot of time to fetch.So I google it and found that json takes less time.Can we fetch data as well as html with the help of json ?

Comment: You can fetch the Json data, and on successful callback, you can make another request to load the HTML. But if the HTML is only some textboxes & labels, that you can also create in runtime based on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data key/attribute and use the POST method, but don't pass the queries through the URL.

```
$(".nks_cc_trigger_element").click(function(){
    var str = $(this).attr("data-product_id");
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_product.php",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: //json data,
      success: function(result){
        //success code
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
        //error code
      }
    });
});
```